# Find All Running Processes Based on a Regular Expression

Tags: linux

How can I find a list of all running processes, and use a regular expression to filter on the command column.

`ps aux` is what I am using to get a list of all running processes, but I just need to filter on that command column for any processes that have "pentaho" in the name. The regular expression might look like this:

```
(?i).*pentaho.*
```

(case insensitive)

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux and Unix installations have a command named `pgrep` for this.  The `p` in the command name is for `process`.  Check the man page to ensure your `pgrep` supports the particular regular expression you're wanting to use.  The `-f` option (to match the `full command line` instead of just process name) is often useful.

There's a companion command named `pkill` because very often the reason you're searching through processes is because you want to send a signal to one of them.  `pkill` does that, and has additional options to specify the signal you want to send - much like the regular `kill` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ps aux command along with the grep command to filter the output based on a regular expression.

`ps aux | grep -i ".*pentaho.*"`

Comment: This will usually also catch the grep process itself and hence is most of the time less preferable than just using `pgrep`

Comment: As a trick (for when you're in a hurry and don't remember the `pgrep` options), you can use a bracket expression around part of grep's expression:  `ps aux | grep '.*pe[n]taho.*'`.  The grep regex in the ls output won't match its own regex argument.